# Process "dotnet" crashes when creating OpenTK texture

Tags: c#, opengl, .net-core, textures, opentk

I am building an opengl app in dotnet core 2.0 using ImageSharp and OpenTk

When I call `GL.TexImage2D` with a pointer to my image data the dotnet runtime crashes

How can I solve or work around this issue?

```
using OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL4;
using System;
using ImageSharp;

namespace Processing.OpenTk.Core.Textures
{
    public struct Texture2d
    {
        public readonly int Handle;
        public readonly int Width;
        public readonly int Height;

        public Texture2d(int[] data, int width, int height)
        {
            Width = width;
            Height = height;
            Handle = GL.GenTexture();
            GL.Enable(EnableCap.Texture2D);            
            GL.BindTexture(TextureTarget.Texture2D, Handle);            
            unsafe
            {
                fixed (int* dataptr = &data[0])
                {
                    GL.TexImage2D(TextureTarget.Texture2D, 0, PixelInternalFormat.Rgba, Width, Height, 0, PixelFormat.Bgra, PixelType.Int, (IntPtr)dataptr);
                    GL.BindTexture(TextureTarget.Texture2D, 0);                    
                }
                GL.Disable(EnableCap.Texture2D);
            }            
        }

        public static implicit operator int(Texture2d texture) => texture.Handle;

        public static Texture2d FromFile(string file) => FromImage(Image.Load(file));         

        public static Texture2d FromImage(Image<Rgba32> image)
        {
            var pixels = new int[image.Pixels.Length];
            int[] data = new int[image.Pixels.Length];

            for (int i = 0; i < image.Pixels.Length; i++)   
            {         
                data[i] = image.Pixels[i].R << 24 | image.Pixels[i].G << 16 | image.Pixels[i].B << 8 | image.Pixels[i].A;                            
            }
            return new Texture2d(data, image.Width, image.Height);
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: The pixel type `PixelType.Int` won't work, because each color channel (and the alpha channel) is encoded in one byte, probably you have to change it to `PixelType.UnsignedByte`. (see [`glTexImage2D`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTexImage2D.xhtml) )

Comment: So PixelType is actually "Each Color Type" not the whole pixel type?
All I have now is a black square, the image loaded was not a black square

Comment: @Rabbid76 that's beyond the scope of this question (process was crashing during loading because of the memory access issue). I should create another question if I need to about the black square